# IE8 won't load JavaScript file in "Compatibility View."

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

Here's my JS insert:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/profile.js"></script>
```

In IE8 with "Compatibility View," the file never loads. The first line in the file is a simple alert() call, so that I know it loaded. Change the browser to Standards View, and it loads fine.

Also, if I add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" >
```

It forces to Standards View and it loads fine.

Any idea why this would be the case? I've not been able to test against IE7, but I know the JS file *also* does not load in IE6.

Right now the  tag is in the  section of the file.

Comment: So, I've gotten IE7 running in a VM and it has the same behavior as IE8 in "Compatibility View." 

There are no JS errors.

I've installed the dev toolbar, and it "sees" the <script> tag, but it doesn't appear to be loading it. Again - no JS errors at all. I've moved the <script> tag to various locations in the file - no dice.

Comment: This HAS to be something related to the way it's parsing the file. It's gotta be barfing on something but not throwing an error. I'm going to try breaking it down into tiny pieces to see where it starts working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that IE8, Safari, Firefox, et al will tolerate certain JavaScript syntax errors. IE7 and IE6 (and IE8 in 'compatibility view') will not, and they will also not throw a parse error or any other kind of clue.

Pasting my code into http://www.jslint.com/ revealed a couple of syntax errors that weren't affecting the code's operation in other browsers. So boo on me.

Comment: The usual suspect is the trailing comma in list and object literals.

Comment: Absolutely correct. That's what it was. JSLint made it very easy to spot them.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Had the same problem on IE8 and safari 5 on windows and finally got this working. This one is really beauty...

I had a function with a parameter named 'class' which was causing the issue. Renaming to clsname fixed the problem. Apparently FF and chrome were lenient about this.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on script debugging and see if you are getting a javascript error in compatibility mode.  The presence of an error would keep the javascript from executing even if it is loaded.  You might also want to use the developer tools in IE8 to debug the javascript and/or verify if the file is loaded or not.

Comment: This has something to do with IE7 mode - because IE7 does the same thing. Not getting any JS errors at all. It "sees" the JS file, and in IE8 I can see the source for the file... but it's like it isn't parsing it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

just spent couple of hours on this - IE7 & 8 suffers from "return" identificator
I had:

```
m["return"] = 123;
var x = m.return; // SILENT ERROR!
```

Obviously, renamaing identificator solves this